# is system.properties only a Heroku thing?

Tags: java, heroku

This is super hard to Google for because it removes the ".". I'm new to Java and setting up a Java app in Heroku. There is a file `system.properties` that lets us specify the Java version we want to use.

The contents are like:

```
java.runtime.version=1.8
```

I'm just wondering, who created the "standard" for having a system.properties file? Is that only used by Heroku? Or does that standard come from somewhere else in the Java world?

Answer (score 3):

It's just a property file named `system`. It has no special meaning unless something reads that file and does something based on the contents (like in this case Heroku).

So it's a standard in the sense that property files contain key-value pairs like that, but `system.properties` is not a "Java wide" standard.

Answer (score 2):

`system.properties` is part of the Heroku configuration. Among other things, it allows you to specify the Java version you'd be using (i.e., which java binary will run your code), so it cannot be part of Java itself.